# Facebook redirect with extended permissions

Tags: facebook

I am trying to work out facebook connect based on this tutorial:
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-authenticate-your-users-with-facebook-connect/

They have given you a few scripts to use to figure it out, this is the extended permissions one:

```
<?php
# We require the library
require("facebook.php");

# Creating the facebook object
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
 'appId'  => '...',
 'secret' => '...',
 'cookie' => true
));

# Let's see if we have an active session
$session = $facebook->getSession();

if(!empty($session)) {
 # Active session, let's try getting the user id (getUser()) and user info (api->('/me'))
 try{
  $uid = $facebook->getUser();

  # req_perms is a comma separated list of the permissions needed
  $url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
   'req_perms' => 'email,user_birthday,status_update,publish_stream,user_photos,user_videos'
  ));
  header("Location: {$url} ");
 } catch (Exception $e){}
} else {
 # There's no active session, let's generate one
 $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
 header("Location: ".$login_url);
}
```

When I execute this it lets me allow the extended permissions but then I get a redirect loop error. When I check in facebook it has granted extended permissions.

Now I tried to just implement it into the login script they gave, which is this

```
# We require the library
require("facebook.php");

# Creating the facebook object
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
 'appId'  => '...',
 'secret' => '...',
 'cookie' => true
));

# Let's see if we have an active session
$session = $facebook->getSession();

if(!empty($session)) {
 # Active session, let's try getting the user id (getUser()) and user info (api->('/me'))
 try{
  $uid = $facebook->getUser();
  $user = $facebook->api('/me');

 } catch (Exception $e){}

 if(!empty($user)){
  # We have an active session, let's check if we have already registered the user
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE oauth_prov = 1 AND oauth_id = ". $user['id']);
  $result = mysql_fetch_array($query);

  # If not, let's add it to the database

  echo $user['id'] . $user['name'];

  if(empty($result)){
   $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (oauth_prov, oauth_id, username) VALUES ('1', {$user['id']}, '{$user['name']}')");
   $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = " . mysql_insert_id());
   $result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
  }

  // this sets variables in the session 
  $_SESSION['id'] = $result['id'];
  $_SESSION['oauth_uid'] = $result['oauth_id'];
  $_SESSION['oauth_provider'] = $result['oauth_provider'];
  $_SESSION['username'] = $result['username'];



 } else {
  # For testing purposes, if there was an error, let's kill the script
  die("There was an error.");
 }
} else {
 # There's no active session, let's generate one
 $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
 header("Location: ".$login_url);
}
```

However, I don't know where it should go, as I would like to request permissions at the same time as the login to get the users details. If I put this:

```
try{
  $uid = $facebook->getUser();

  # req_perms is a comma separated list of the permissions needed
  $url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
   'req_perms' => 'email,user_birthday,status_update,publish_stream,user_photos,user_videos'
  ));
  header("Location: {$url} ");


 } catch (Exception $e){}
```

After I set the session values then I don't even get to allow anything, it just hangs and I get a redirect error.
If I put it just after getting the facebook user_id then it gives me the allow dialog (although one after the other as its obviously asking twice, something I would like to stop) but then again gives me a redirect error, having granted the extended permissions

I really don't have a clue where to put it, the documentation for facebook is absolutely abysmal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
# req_perms is a comma separated list of the permissions needed
$url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('req_perms' => 'email,user_birthday,status_update,publish_stream,user_photos,user_videos'));
```

try:

```
$url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'email,user_birthday,status_update,publish_stream,user_photos,user_videos'));
```

for an complete example see the php-sdk:
https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php

Comment: scope actually isn't included in the example, it's more like an incomplete example.

Comment: things change, but here you can find the function @ line 512:
https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/src/base_facebook.php

You can also read up on it here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl/